# Likebox not showing old posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I don't post very often on my Facebook page and so my like box is not showing posts.  Why can't it just show the most recent posts no matter how old they are?

The bottom line is I need my posts to show in my like box or for SEO reasons.  If they aren't showing there's no point in having a like box on my site.

Also, is there any way to get rid of the login dialog that shows if a user isn't logged in.  It doesn't look very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same complaint - ever since the switch to timeline, seems like there needs to be some activity at least once a month, and all older activities are compressed under the "more" bar by default.  Kind of sucks, makes the plug in less interesting.